# How to send an image with text in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing an application for windows phone 7 that has pictures of seven cards where User write a message on top of the image. How do I send the image over the message by email?

Answer (score 0):

You can send an email using the Email Compose Task which you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394003%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). Unfortunately it only supports text emails (No HTML), so you wont be able to add an image.

Comment: thanks for answering my question.
The application I developed is available: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/search?q=Christmas% 20PhoneCard